# MPI communicator for sub-range of MPI_COMM_WORLD

Tags: mpi, communicator

What is a simple way to create a (sub)communicator containing consecutive ranks [`rStart`, ..., last rank of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`] of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`?

`rStart` is >= 0, i.e., first `rStart` ranks need to be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest code is to have

```
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank < rStart, rank, &new_comm);
```

run on **all ranks** of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. It will create two communicators - all ranks starting with `rStart` will get the one you desire, the others can just `MPI_Comm_free` their communicator.

If you cannot easily have the excluded ranks run the same code, you can use `MPI_Comm_create_group`, but then you have to also create the group first.

Comment: After reading about `MPI_Comm_split`, I realized that `(rank < rStart ? MPI_UNDEFINED : 0)` is even better for second argument: it will produce `MPI_COMM_NULL` on first ranks.